# Where does the Win10 Toast Notification snoozed data reside?

Tags: powershell

I just created a powershell script to show a toast notification with a Snooze button and time options. This is what I have problems with:

Toast Notification with Snooze option

Every time I execute the script I want to check if there is a previous snoozed notification and, if there is, the scrip will exit not showing a new notification.

[image: Screenshot]

Does anyone knows where does the snoozed notifications data resides?

I tried looking on the registry and Task Scheduler but no luck, I'm sure there has to be some place where it holds the notification until the snooze time finishes to show it again in the Action Center.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed your code that's creating the notifications, or at least described what API/classes/cmdlets/modules you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the answer and I'll post it here in case someone else is looking for it:

```
$app =  '{1AC14E77-02E7-4E5D-B744-2EB1AE5198B7}\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'
$toasts = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::CreateToastNotifier($app)
$notifications = $toasts.GetScheduledToastNotifications()
```

This will get all your scheduled toast notifications and then you can play with that info :)